# Fastest stable algorithm for solving dense symmetric linear system $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am trying to find the fastest algorithm for solving a linear system:

$$
Ax = b.
$$

I know that $A$ will always be symmetric and dense, and will sometimes be positive definite. And $b$ will always be dense as well.
So far, I have thought of two algorithms:

1. If not positive definite => use LDL decomposition
2. If positive definite => use Cholesky decomposition

My question is: is there any practical (one that can be implemented quite easily) algorithm that is faster than the two that I currently have. The algorithm must be stable in terms of its floating point operation. I am using
this as part of a physics engine that I am building, so the matrix will be of quite large dimensions, thus I would like the asymptotic time to be as small as
possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: use LAPACK's `dsysv` or if positive definite `dposv`

Comment: Don't try to re-invent the wheel.  There are highly optimized libraries for linear algebra that will almost surely outperform anything you could implement yourself.

Comment: If $A$ is re-used then you should use some pre-factorization technique, otherwise you should just do direct solution. In either case you should just use LAPACK or a wrapper to it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. LAPACK looks interesting, I will look into it, but I am still interested to know what algorithm will potentially be faster? does LAPACK provide a list of the algorithms it uses to solve linear symmetric systems?

Comment: Most routines in LAPACK are specific algorithms, unlike MATLAB where something like the backslash operator will often spend some time inspecting the problem to decide on what to do before doing it and not telling you what exactly it did.